# Measure CPU usage starting from OS boot

Tags: c, kernel, reverse-engineering, device-driver

How to write and run program capable of showing CPU usage starting from OS boot time?

I'd like to measure how much processor, hard disk and RAM is being used during system start-up.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 or Win 7 or any other on which it'll be easier to implement that.

Comment: Way too broad. You haven't even told us anything about 1) the OS 2) the processor, or 3) the bootcode that you're using. And you aren't going to write and run a program, you're going to hack the bootcode and the hard disk driver.

Comment: I have edited my question. It is broad question, as I would like to hear if anyone have tried doing this on any OS.

Comment: I've done this on an embedded OS (no hard drive), to optimize the boot time. Highly unlikely that you can get anything out of Win7. Ubuntu, maybe.

Comment: Do you recollect any of conclusions and care to write it? I couldn't find single mention of anybody doing this, while searching in Google.

Comment: The place to start is [U-boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) since that can be the boot code for a linux system.

Answer (score 1):

Windows: you can call GetTickCount64 to get the time since the system was started, and QueryIdleProcessorCycleTime to get idle time. Subtract to get the time spent doing something useful.

As for HDD and RAM usage depends on what do you mean by 'used'... Number of reads? writes? Allocated pages? Committed pages? Virtual or physical memory? Page file requests - are they considered as HDD or RAM usage?